# Remove text before last specified special character in Excel

Tags: excel

I've got a list of categories in a breadcrumb trail, and I need to extract the latest category.

Below is a sample of the list, and I need to get the category after the last /, or if there is no /, then the category.  So the following would turn into the below.

**Before**

```
Sewing
Crafting/Paper & Paper Crafts
Scrapbooking & Stamping
Crafting/Craft Supplies
Painting, Drawing & Art Supplies/Painting/Brushes
Beading & Jewelry Making/Charms
Beading & Jewelry Making/Beading Supplies
```

**After**

```
Sewing
Paper & Paper Crafts
Scrapbooking & Stamping
Craft Supplies
Brushes
Charms
Beading Supplies
```

Can anyone point me to an excel formula that can do this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [SUBSTITUTE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/substitute-function-2bdd8fb3-d756-4656-8aa4-e871e6578671) to create a large gap of spaces at the forward slashes then peel off the right end and use the [TRIM function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TRIM-function-410388FA-C5DF-49C6-B16C-9E5630B479F9) to clean it up.

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1, "/", REPT(" ", 999)), 999))
```

Fill down as necessary.

[image: SUBSTITUTE with RIGHT and TRIM]